# PHP MySQL generate new value until no match

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

I want to create a new key until this key doesn't already exist in my MySQL database:

```
$myLocalKey = generateNewKey();
while(mysql_num_rows(mysql_query('SELECT mykey FROM ' . DB_TABLE . ' WHERE mykey="' . mysql_real_escape_string($myLocalKey) . '"')) > 0) {
        $myLocalKey = generateNewKey();
}
```

But it doesn't seem to work. I get an Error 500 message. What am I doing wrong?

All the keys inside the database have a value already... So PHP should check if the PHP generated key doesn't exist already and if it does generate a new one until it finds one that doesn't exist yet.

Comment: Why does it seem not to work? Do you get an error message? Please edit your question.

Comment: I get an error 500... Added it to my answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are not adding the key into the database. So how is that query meant to run?

You are currently

```
 /**
**Generating a key But you are not adding it into the db so it will not select anything hence your loop will keep running?
**/  
 $myLocalKey = generateNewKey();
    while(mysql_num_rows(mysql_query('SELECT mykey FROM ' . DB_TABLE . ' WHERE mykey="' . mysql_real_escape_string($myLocalKey) . '"')) > 0) {
            $myLocalKey = generateNewKey();
    }
```

here one solution

```
/**
    **GENERATE KEY
    **/
    $myLocalKey = generateNewKey();

    /**
    **RUN A QUERY TO CHECK IF KEY EXISTS IF IT DOES NOT ADD IT TO DB.?
    **/
    $query = mysql_query('SELECT mykey FROM ' . DB_TABLE . ' WHERE mykey="' . mysql_real_escape_string($myLocalKey) . '"');

do{
    /**
    **GENERATE KEY
    **/
    $myLocalKey = generateNewKey();

    /**
    **RUN A QUERY TO CHECK IF KEY EXISTS IF IT DOES NOT ADD IT TO DB.?
    **/
    $query = mysql_query('SELECT mykey FROM ' . DB_TABLE . ' WHERE mykey="' . mysql_real_escape_string($myLocalKey) . '"');

    if(mysql_num_rows($query) < 1) {

    /**
    ** INSERT QUERY TO ADD KEY
    */
    }

}while(mysql_num_rows($query) < 1);
```

Comment: I have had the insert statement outside of the loop...
Your code works perfect, thanks alot!

Comment: no problem, mate ive had problems like this in the past so i knew ;)

Comment: two suggestions tho first one being use PDO rather than mysql http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html and the other one is performance the script is not he fastest. So challenge to you is to select the keys you have already got in db and then use the do while to check the keys and generate them than insert them as one. That could be about 5 maybe 10x faster ;)

Answer (score 0):

## 1

Try to use the mysqli versions (`mysqli_query` and `mysqli_num_rows`). These calls may be deprecated.

## 2

Free your results at the end of every iteration (last line in your while body) with `mysqli_free_result`. It could be that you get a buffer overflow.

Comment: Please check if your sql query works in a simpler scenario like this: if(mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT mykey FROM " . DB_TABLE . " WHERE mykey="1'")) > 0) { echo "Test"; }. I have the feeling somethings wrong with that query.

Comment: And try to use the mysqli versions (mysqli_query and mysqli_num_rows). Your version is deprecated in PHP 5.5.0. BTW which PHP version are you using actually?

Comment: And finally (poor i forgot that) free your results at the end of every iteration (last line in your while body) every iteration with  mysqli_free_result()! It could be that you get a buffer overflow.

Comment: Thanks. I got your point and used my comments provided so far to update my answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
$myKey = generateKey();
while(mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT mykey FROM " . DB_TABLE . " WHERE mykey='" . mysql_real_escape_string($myKey) . "'")) > 0) {
        $myKey= generateKey();
}
```